# Total count of objects in Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

*Using Django ~=1.11 and Python 3.6*

I am a beginner! Every answer I've found online for my question is more advanced than what I'm looking for.

Here's my model:

```
class Byte(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Here's my view:

```
def byte_list(request):
    bytes = Byte.objects.order_by('text')
    return render(request, 'cloudapp/byte_list.html', {'bytes': bytes})
```

Here's my template:

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="total">
        <h2>Total number of words and phrases entered: {{ byte.count }}</h2>
    </div>
<hr>
{% for byte in bytes %}
    <div class="byte">
        <h2>{{ byte.text }}</h2>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

This allows the creation "Byte" objects in the /admin, with only one field - a small text field. Right now, the template simply displays a list of all the objects created.

**Question/Problem:** I'd like to display the total number/count of objects that have been created for the Byte model. In the template, I have a tag {{ byte.count }} to display this.

I've tried using count() and Aggregation, but not sure how to work those into my model/view/template. I'm looking for the most simple and up-to-date way to accomplish this, whether it's using a method or @property in the model, or some type of query set in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with Exprator's answer, but one alternative is to use the built in `length` template filter:

```
<h2>Total number of words and phrases entered: {{ bytes|length }}</h2>
```

If you're not planning to iterate over the `bytes` queryset you could also call `count` on it directly in the template:

```
<h2>Total number of words and phrases entered: {{ bytes.count }}</h2>
```

That will force a second database query, though, so only do that if you aren't otherwise causing `bytes` to be evaluated.

The decision of what to put in the view and what to do with template filters/no-arg methods is more a question of style than a hard and fast rule. Erring on the side of using the view is usually right, here it's simple enough that I might just do it in the template.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about filtering in the template. The thing is... I want to use this value in another calculation. I forgot to mention this.

Comment: If you're doing calculations with it, definitely do it in the view.

Answer (score 6):

You've got a few different options... the most common ways to get the total number of model instances I have seen are:

```
my_total = len(Byte.objects.filter())
```

or, without having to run the full query:

```
my_total = Byte.objects.count()
```

Here's a link to the resource doc for 1.11: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

Comment: Thanks. Would this be placed in the model or the view?

Comment: Definitely in the view, where you actually want to do something with the returned value... you could, for example, have 50 instances, then run the above in your view and pass the variable `my_total` into your template, or anything else, to say "you have {{ my_total }} Byte objects".

Comment: Thanks. My eyes are opening wider.

Answer (score 2):

```
def byte_list(request):
    byte= Byte.objects.count()
    bytes = Byte.objects.order_by('text')
    return render(request, 'cloudapp/byte_list.html', {'bytes': bytes,'byte':byte})
```

And in template

```
 {{ byte }}
```

Comment: Generally sound, but the docs recommend loading the queryset into memory and using `len` if you're going to need the queryset anyway. `count()` is faster than `len` if you're not loading it, but here `bytes` will be needed so `{'bytes': bytes, 'byte_count': len(bytes)}` probably comes out faster. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#count

Comment: Thanks. How would I render this in the template? If I make this change, it shows nothing.

Comment: Whatever key you use in the context dict (`byte` in @Exprator's version, `byte_count` in my comment) will be available as a context variable, so just `{{ byte_count }}` should work.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention in template it will be {{ byte }}. Will update the ans

Comment: If I wanted to use this value in a calculation, could I do that? If so, would this "count" need to be done in the model as a method or property?

Comment: You can do this in the view and do the calculation what you need to do in the view and send it to the template

Comment: Thanks for your help!